# CakePHP - Reenter Password on Page Submit

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, passwords

I am new to CakePHP and have a requirement to prompt (admin) users to reenter their password on page submit. Page, where validation needs to be added is for modifying sub-users' information.  I have tried to find a solution on Stack Overflow and other forums but no luck.

Here are more details:

We have 3 buttons on edit.ctp that "enable", "disable" and "delete" sub users by changing their statuses in Users table.

```
 echo $this->Form->button('Enable', array('onclick'=> 'change_status(1);'));

            echo $this->Form->button('Disable', array('onclick'=> 'change_status(0);'));

            echo $this->Form->button('Delete', array('onclick'=> 'change_status(2);'));
```

There is a hidden text field which is bound to status field of the Users table. It can have 3 values: 1 (enabled), 0 (disabled) and 2 (deleted). 
PS: We can't remove users' records because of certain reasons so relying on these "statuses". This field is updated when user clicks any of the 3 buttons

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('user.status', array('label' => false, 'type' => 'text' , 'value'=> $user["User"]["status"], 'id' => 'status_id'));
```

## JavaScript function

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function change_status(status){
                  document.getElementById("status_id").value = status;
             }
       </script>
```

Now, we need to prompt user to reenter their password when they click any of the 3 buttons. And in case password doesn't match login password, they shouldn't be allowed to perform the action.

Comment: You need to show your (specific) code, and ask a specific code-related question for it to be on topic for stackoverflow. Also note that the question you've asked is not (conceptually) CakePHP specific.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited the question. I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have users table in your database (otherwise you can modify yourself). In Users Controller,

```
public function checkPassword($userid,$password)
{
    $hashed_pwd = $this->User->passwordHash($password); // call passwordHash function in User.php model
    $condition = array('User.id'=>$userid,'User.password'=>$hashed_pwd);

    if($this->User->hasAny($condition)) // check if password with that userid exists in users table
    {
        $output['status'] = 1; // give access
    } else {
        $output['status'] = 0
    }

    $this->set('output'=>$output);

}
```

In User model,

```
public function passwordHash($password) {
    return   AuthComponent::password($password);

}
```

In your view you can check response given by checkPassword function written in controller.

Comment: I have been trying to call the function but getting the error of Missing Parameter 2. First parameter is passed (I can print it on the screen from the function checkPassword) but 2nd one doesn't.

$parameters = $userId.'/'.$userPassword;
  
$result = $this->requestAction('/users/checkPassword/'.$parameters);

Error:

Warning (2): Missing argument 2 for UsersController::checkPassword() [APP/controllers/users_controller.php, line 118]

Comment: if so, remove 2nd parameter from the checkPassword function and take the password as something like : 
     $password = $this->request->data['User']['password']; //$password assigned to the form password , 

from that function.